# Sending body option in headers in request

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

i'm trying to make a post request using this [sync-request](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/sync-request) library. And they don't support body options, so i need set manually in the headers, but i don't know exactly how.

Currently i'm trying like this:

```
 let req = request('POST', LINK, {
    'headers': {
      'Accept'                    : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
      'Accept-Encoding'           : 'gzip, deflate',
      'Accept-Language'           : 'en-US,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.6',
      'body'                      : 'ESTCS=1; ESTID=00726861000151',
      'Cache-Control'             : 'max-age=0',
      'Connection'                : 'keep-alive',
      'Content-Length'            : '167',
      'Content-Type'              : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Referer'                   : 
      'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' : '1',
      'User-Agent'                : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2584.0 Safari/537.36',
      'X-FirePHP-Version'         : '0.0.6'
    }
  });
```

But nothing happens.

I need send two things in my body:

```
let body = {
  'ESTCS': 1,
  'ESTID': '00726861000151'
};
```

i'm trying like this:

```
'body': 'ESTCS=1; ESTID=00726861000151',
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Body should be & separated. Try it this way:

```
'body': 'ESTCS=1&ESTID=00726861000151',
```